# Which cmd commands have been deprecated?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I know that xcopy is marked as deprecated, with Robocopy being its replacement.
Now I found that cacls is also deprecated, with Icacls as its replacement.

Are there more commands which are now deprecated? I could check them all manually but it's a long list.

Comment: Good question, I can't find any official list. Best bet is to do a DIFF on the 'help' outputs between versions. And also system exe diffs. I can supply the Vista parts ;)

Comment: Agree to Monkey) +1 to both.

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it, wouldn't it suffice just to apply /? to each command in the help list, save the output to .txt format and then look for the word "deprecated" in them. I think it would be logical to expect the mentioning of a replacement when this condition is met

Comment: I disagree about xcopy: http://superuser.com/questions/75545/which-cmd-commands-have-been-deprecated/75854#75854

Comment: On my Windows 11 machine, CACLS is still there, but LCACLS isn't present.  Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify from what OS, i'll consider from Windows XP

The NET PRINT command has been deprecated in Windows 7. the WINMAIL too ...

but you have to keep in mind that there is some feature not enabled by default on Windows 7 (ie TELNET) u have to add them from **Turn Windows Feature On or OFF**.

Wikipedia have a nice [list of features removed in Windows 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_7#Other_Windows_applications_and_features), combined with [List of features removed in Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_Vista) this make a huge list

by the way, they need $7.5M USD :)

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681713%28WS.10%29.aspx) another list from *TechNet*.

Answer (score 0):

- Net Print
- Net Time
- netsh firewall
- strdup
- xcopy :(
- command
- And many more. This happens all the time, but it always makes me a little sad.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in Windows 10 `AT` has been depreciated, so use `schtasks` instead to schedule tasks.